# Using only part of a function in R

Tags: r, math

Is there any way to use only part of a function in R?
*For example*:

```
My.function <- function(x)
{
  m = mean(x)
  q.1 = quantile(x, 1/4)
  q.3 = quantile(x, 3/4)
  rbind(m, q.1, q.3)
}
```

I want to use only **q.1** and **q.3** and not **m** for any reason. Is it possible? If it is, then how?
Thanks

Comment: if you put a parameter extra in your function you can put just a conditional and avoid it, but I guess that you want something more robust and general.

Comment: One approach would be to copy the function and edit the last line to only `rbind(q.1,q.3)`. You can get the source for any function in R by simply typing the name of the function without `()` and pressing Enter.

Comment: You can't run only part of a function. You'll need to either change the function or write a new one.

Comment: Hi,  as advice to a newcomer:  don't rush to accept an answer.  Give it a day or so to see what other answers show up, as a better (for you) approach may come along.

Answer (score 1):

You could use if statements in the body of the function and add booleans in the function argument. Then the function won't evaluate if statements that are false. For your case, it would be something like

```
 My.function <- function(x,getmean = F)
{
  q.1 = quantile(x, 1/4)
  q.3 = quantile(x, 3/4)

  if (getmean) {
    m = mean(x)
    return(rbind(m, q.1, q.3))
  } else {
    return(rbind(q.1,q.3))
  }
}

#test 
My.function(rnorm(100))
My.function(rnorm(100), getmean = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you bother?  If you don't want the `m` in your output, just write

```
foo <- My.function(x)[2:3,]
```

Note: if you are dealing with a function which contains three seriously time-consuming subfunctions, then it makes sense to do something similar to "doubled"s answer.  I would recommend full flexibility:

```
 My.function <- function(x, dolist=c(1,1,1) )
{
result <-vector('list') # to handle any sorts of results
if(dolist[1])   { result[[1]] <- first.function(x) }
if(dolist[2])   {result[[2]] <- second.function(x) }
if(dolist[3])  {result[[3]] <- third.function(x) }
return(result)
}
```